# Duplicate existing contacts alert

Tags: vtiger

In Vtiger 6.5.0 open source, I wants to create a alert function to warn users that the conact's mobile is existing? could you please help me. I'm fresher.

Thanks,
Loi

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the function wich exist in Account module for checking Duplicate Account Name.

Please follow this files you will get an idea.

This is the code flow how its done In Account Module

Registring Pre Save Event
http://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/blob/master/layouts/vlayout/modules/Accounts/resources/Edit.js#L250

This teh Fucntion to check Duplicate in cache, If not calls the Helper function
http://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/blob/master/layouts/vlayout/modules/Accounts/resources/Edit.js#L83

This the Helper function which makes the call to server
http://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/blob/master/resources/helper.js#L166

This is the action function which is responsible for Serving the request which came from Helper Function
http://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/blob/master/modules/Accounts/actions/CheckDuplicate.php#L30

And this is the function which checks for Duplicate
http://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/blob/master/modules/Accounts/models/Record.php#L57

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Salim. I tried but still not work. :(

Comment: Did you check whether the event is triggering and it is making a call to server, when you click Save button. You can see the calls in browser console

Comment: how do we check when user create new contacts in Opportunities?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Victor please follow this steps

modules\Leads\actions\Checkprimaryemail.php

```
<?php

    class Leads_Checkprimaryemail_Action extends Vtiger_BasicAjax_Action {

        public function checkPermission(Vtiger_Request $request) {
            return;
        }

        public function process(Vtiger_Request $request) {
            global $adb;
            $moduleName = $request->get('module');
            $recordId = $request->get('recordId');
            $primary_email = $request->get('primary_email');

            /*Lead Details*/
            $lead_query = "select * from vtiger_leaddetails
                     inner join vtiger_crmentity on vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_leaddetails.leadid 
                     where vtiger_crmentity.deleted = 0 and vtiger_leaddetails.email='".$primary_email."'";
            $lead_result = $adb->query($lead_query);
            $lead_email = $adb->query_result($lead_result,0,'email');
            $lead_numrows = $adb->num_rows($lead_result);

            /*Contact Details*/
            $cont_query = "select * from vtiger_contactdetails
                     inner join vtiger_crmentity on vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_contactdetails.contactid 
                     where vtiger_crmentity.deleted = 0 and vtiger_contactdetails.email='".$primary_email."'";
            $cont_result = $adb->query($cont_query);
            $cont_email = $adb->query_result($cont_result,0,'email');
            $cont_numrows = $adb->num_rows($cont_result);

            if($recordId != '' ){
                if($primary_email == $lead_email && $lead_numrows == 1 ){
                    $emailtrue = 0;
                } elseif($primary_email == $cont_email && $cont_numrows >= 1 ) {
                    $emailtrue = 1;
                }
            } else {
                if(($lead_numrows >=1 || $cont_numrows >=1 ) ||  ($lead_numrows >=1 && $cont_numrows >= 1)  ){
                    $emailtrue = 1;
                } else {
                    $emailtrue = 0;
                }
            }

            $emailData = array($emailtrue);
            $response = new Vtiger_Response();
            $response->setResult($emailData);
            $response->emit();

        }
    }

    ?>
```

After Create One other file 
layouts\vlayout\modules\Leads\resources\Edit.js

```
Vtiger_Edit_Js("Leads_Edit_Js", {
}, {
    changeEvent: function (container) {
        jQuery('input[name="email"]').on('focusout', function (e) {
            var email = jQuery('input[name="email"]').val();
            var recordId = jQuery('input[name="record"]').val();
            var email_length = email.length;
            if (email != '') {
                if (email_length > 100) {
                    var errorMessage = app.vtranslate('JS_EMAIL_LENGTH_VALIDATION');
                    params = {
                        text: errorMessage,
                        'type': 'error',
                    };
                    Vtiger_Helper_Js.showMessage(params);
                }

                var progressIndicatorElement = jQuery.progressIndicator({
                    'position': 'html',
                    'blockInfo': {
                        'enabled': true
                    }
                });
                var postData = {
                    "module": 'Leads',
                    "action": "Checkprimaryemail",
                    "primary_email": email,
                    "recordId": recordId
                }
                AppConnector.request(postData).then(
                        function (data) {
                            progressIndicatorElement.progressIndicator({'mode': 'hide'});
                            if (data['result'] == 1) {
                                jQuery('#emailalready_exists').val(1);
                                var errorMessage = app.vtranslate('JS_EMAIL_EXIST');
                                params = {
                                    text: errorMessage,
                                    'type': 'error',
                                };
                                Vtiger_Helper_Js.showMessage(params);
                            } else {
                                jQuery('#emailalready_exists').val(0);
                            }
                        },
                        function (error, err) {}
                );
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    },
    registerBasicEvents: function (container) {
        this._super(container);
        this.changeEvent(container);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Chothani, I applied this in Leads and it worked perfect. However, i apply the same logic in contacts, it didn't work.

Comment: if you are use this contact module then Create File in Contact  module with Replace word Leads to Contacts

Answer (score 0):

To check duplicate records in vTiger follow below steps:
Register `checkDuplicate` function in `registerBasicEvents`
1: `\layouts\vlayout\modules\Contacts\resources\Edit.js`

```
getmobile : function(container){
    return jQuery('input[name="mobile"]',container).val();
},
getRecordId : function(container){
    return jQuery('input[name="record"]',container).val();
},
DuplicateCheck : function(form) {
    var thisInstance = this;
    if(typeof form == 'undefined') {
        form = this.getForm();
    }
     jQuery( "#mobileFieldId" ).change(function() {
            var mobile = thisInstance.getmobile(form);

        var recordId = thisInstance.getRecordId(form);
        var params = {
            'module' : "Contacts",
            'action' : "CheckDuplicate",
            'mobile' : mobile,
            'record' : recordId
        }
        AppConnector.request(params).then(
            function(data) {
                var response = data['result'];
                var result = response['success'];
                if(result == true) {
                    var message_params = {
                        title : app.vtranslate('JS_MESSAGE'),
                        text: response['message'],
                        animation: 'show',
                        type: 'error'
                    };
                    Vtiger_Helper_Js.showPnotify(message_params);
                    jQuery(".btn-success").attr('disabled',true);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    jQuery(".btn-success").attr('disabled',false);
                }
            }
        );
     });
   },
```

2: Create new file in** `\modules\Contacts\actions\CheckDuplicate.php`
Follow the same process / code as given in `\modules\Accounts\actions\CheckDuplicate.php`

3: Add new function `checkDuplicate()` in `\modules\Contacts\models\Record.php`

And follow same process as given in `\modules\Accounts\models\Record.php` having `function checkDuplicate()`

Note: Don't forget to change the db table name, class name module wise.

Hope this will help you. Thank you.

Comment: public function checkDuplicate() {
  $db = PearDatabase::getInstance();

  $query = "SELECT 1 FROM vtiger_crmentity c inner join vtiger_contactdetails lad on c.crmid=lad.contactid WHERE setype = ? AND lad.mobile = ? AND deleted = 0";
                $params = array($this->getModule()->getName(), decode_html($this->getName())); 

  $record = $this->getId();
  if ($record) {
   $query .= " AND crmid != ?";
   array_push($params, $record);
  }

  $result = $db->pquery($query, $params);
  if ($db->num_rows($result)) {
   return true;
  }

Comment: There should be problem in your query. Please crosscheck again. Try to debug. Because I followed same way and it works like charm.

Comment: Hi sAcH, could you send your files on this functions via email lethangloi0707@gmail.com.